# Python string equality test delivers inconsistent results

Tags: python

The following function is used in a script to create a static version of a Django site:

```
def write_file(filename, content):
    filename = '{0}{1}.html'.format(BASEDIR, filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        existing_file = io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
        existing_content = existing_file.read()
        existing_file.close()
        if existing_content != content:
            print "Content is not equal, writing file to {0}".format(filename)
            encoded_content = content.encode('utf-8')
            html_file = open(filename, 'w')
            html_file.write(encoded_content)
            html_file.close()
        else:
            print "Content is equal, nothing is written to {0}".format(filename)
```

When I run the script twice (without any changes to the database), one would expect no write operations at all. Strangely enough, more than half of the files are written over and over again.

Comment: There are [better ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) to do caching, you know...

Comment: Why are you not using `io` both times?

Comment: Are you sure `content` is a `unicode` object?

Comment: I do use nginx for caching, the static site is for backup purposes. Using io both times does not affect the results. I tested that content is indeed a Unicode objects (and the equality test does work for several pages, after all). I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Just after the else-clause, add ``print repr(existing_content), repr(content)``.

Comment: @janeden: `str` object actually *can* compare equal to `unicode` objects.  If you compare a `str` object and a `unicode` object, and the `str` object cannot be decoded using the default encoding (usually `ascii` on Python 2.x), they will compare unequal.  This would explain that it works sometimes.

Comment: Had to read it over a few times before I realized that this is not a question.

Comment: Did that, and found the difference (both objects are indeed Unicode objects): In one place, `existing_content` contains `\r\n` where `content` contains `\n`. Other linebreaks for the same page are encoded identically (as `\n`), though. This is odd – why would a single linebreak's encoding get changed each time the string is written to a file?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is symptomatic of data getting encoded twice somewhere in the process or text being compared to unicode.  In Python 2.x, `` abc` == u`abc `` so some files that contain only ASCII will pass the comparison test with the other half of your files have non-ascii characters won't be the same before and after UTF-8 encoding.

The easiest way to tell what is going on is to improve the error reporting in your code:  Just after the else-clause, add:

```
print repr(existing_content), repr(content)
```

Comment: Thanks, Raymond, this was really helpful. As it turned out, the issue was not related to string encoding, but to the linefeed conversion applied by the database server.

Comment: No problem.  Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) module; something like this:

```
import codecs

def write_file(filename, content):
    filename = "{0}{1}.html".format(BASEDIR, filename)   
    if os.path.exists(filename):

        # open file and read into a utf8 string.
        # Calling open(), read(), then close() can all be made into 1 call.
        # python will handle the closing and gc for you
        existing_content = codecs.open(filename, "r", "utf-8").read()

        if existing_content != content.encode("utf-8"):
            print "Content is not equal, writing file to {0}".format(filename)
            
            # python will close the open fd for you after this
            # codecs will handle the utf8 conversion before writing to the file, so no need to encode 'content'
            codecs.open(filename, "w", "utf-8").write(content)

            # Although, it might be necessary to write the utf-8 Byte-Order Marker first:
            outF = open(filename, "w")
            outF.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
            outF.write(content.encode("utf-8"))
            outF.close()
        else:
            print "Content is equal, nothing is written to {0}".format(filename)
```

Lots of good info: [How to use utf-8 with python](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html)

Comment: A lot of helpful comments/answers – but it turned out the problem was not related to Unicode objects vs. encoded strings. Instead, the database server converted each linebreak to `\r\n`, while the linebreaks read from the file came out as `\n`. A pragmatic solution was to add `content = content.replace('\r\n', '\n')` to the function before comparing `content` to `existing_content`.